# Performance of string operations in Dyalog

Tags: vector, comparison, apl, dyalog

I have 2 questions related to comparing character vectors in Dyalog APL.
The following code will compare character vectors one-by-one:

```
a←'ATCG'
b←'GTCA'
a=b
```

- In order to speed up (**in case of 2 vectors, as well as in case of comparing many vectors to a single vector**), should I convert character vector to a numeric vector or it won't matter in APL (similar to comparing chars in C)?
- I am comparing DNA sequences (which may consist of letter from the `ATCG` alphabet only). Is there anything I can do to speed up various operations on such vectors?

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter because at the end of the day, the characters are encoded some way numerically and the comparison would be a number comparison. I'm not sure if there are any advantages given a small alphabet. However, if you don't care 'how' two strings mismatch/match but rather whether or not they are the same, I would recommend using the match operator which returns 1 if equivalent, 0 otherwise (I'm guessing it'll return quickly once a single diff has been found)

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, on my (old) version of Dyalog APL, converting characters to small integers actually runs some 25% faster.  This may have been sped up in more recent versions.

Try

```
a <- []av iota 'ATCG'   // sorry, no apl characters
b <- []av iota 'GTCA'
a = b
```

Be sure that the largest value is less than 128.

To check that you have the smallest possible representation of integers, use the []dr function.  []dr a should return 82 for an integer -128 <= x <= 127.

Dyalog APL will automagically convert to the lowest possible integer width.